# About an irreducible representation over an algebraically closed field

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I want to prove the following statement that is an of the book "A course in the theory of groups" by D. Robinson:

Let $n$ be the degree of an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ over an algebraically closed field. Prove that $n^2\le \vert G:Z(G)\vert$.

The hint of this exercise is: "Use the following theorem"

[image]

I can prove this statement over the field of complex numbers, but over any algebraically closed fields, I don't have any useful ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What facts have you used about $\mathbb{C}$ in your proof? If none of them are really properties that are inherent to $\mathbb{C}$ that aren't true in all algebraically closed fields, then your proof should go straight across.

Comment: @tharris: Over $\mathbb{C}$, we can use some facts about inner product of characters because $Char(\mathbb{C})=0$, but in this case, I know that I cannot use that facts. Actually, the case over complex numbers is Corollary 2.30 of the book "Character theory" by M. Isaacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $A$ a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. The Artin-Wedderburn Theorem tells us that $\dim_k(S)^2 \leq \dim_k(A)$ for all simple $A$-modules $S$.

Now, if $S$ is a simple $kG$-module, then by Schur's Lemma there exists a $\theta : Z(G) \to k^*$ such that $z x = \theta(z) x$ for all $z \in Z(G)$ and $x \in S$. Hence, $S$ becomes a simple $kG/I$ -module where $I = \langle \theta(z)1 - z \;|\; z \in Z(G) \rangle$. Note that a basis of $kG/I$ is given by representatives for the cosets of $G/Z(G)$, hence $\dim_k(kG/I) = |G:Z(G)|$ and putting things together we obtain $\dim_k(S)^2 \leq \dim_k(kG/I) = |G:Z(G)|$.

**EDIT:**

Using the theorem of Burnside, we can prove the statement in the following way.

Let $S$ be a simple $kG$-module and $\rho : kG \to \text{End}_k(S), g \mapsto (x \mapsto x s) $ the corresponding representation. Then the theorem tells us that this map is surjective.

Now, similarly to the first proof we have $I \subseteq \ker(\rho)$ and so we get an induced homomorphism $kG/I \to \text{End}_k(S)$ which is also surjective. This gives $$|G:Z(G)| = \dim_k(kG/I) \geq \dim_k \text{End}_k(S) = \dim_k(S)^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is there any direction to prove this statement without using Artin-Wedderburn Theorem? I am asking this question because I am a beginner in studying the representation theory and I am not completely familiar with some parts of your proof.

Comment: Do you think using the results of the first chapter of Isaac's 'Character Theory' instead would be better for you? Also, please tell me what other parts of my proof you are not familiar with. Then I will try to go into more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your favor. Actually, I have studied representation theory from chapter 8 of the book "A course in the theory of groups" by D. Robinson. So, I know all materials in this chapter and I understand some parts of your proof, but not all of them. My question is the exercise 8.1.12 of the Robinson'n book and the hint of this exercise is "Use theorem 8.1.8" that is Burnside's theorem (this theorem is added to my question).

Comment: I edited my answer. The hint makes things indeed a bit easier. Again, just tell me if you need more details.